# New Xubuntu grub-update can't find original encrypted Fedora install

Tags: linux, multi-boot, fedora, grub2, disk-encryption

So, I got a shiny new LimeSDR. I have a Lenovo X230 laptop that was running Fedora 27 (may have been 26, but I don't think so). I tried for a while to install software for the LimeSDR, but I ran into weird compilation errors so I decided to install Ubuntu in order to use the LimeSDR PPA. Specifically, I chose to install the XFCE version, Xubuntu.

Fedora is installed on an encrypted partition of the laptop's 128GB SSD. I was worried about exactly this happening, so I tried to find a copy of Xubuntu that would install without overwriting Grub, with no luck. After I installed Xubuntu, I got a grub prompt with only Xubuntu, which I expected. However, when I went to run `update-grub`, Fedora wasn't found.

```
└──> sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

This is what is shown with or without the encrypted disk unlocked. These images are Xubuntu. I've tried, unsuccessfully, to manually boot Fedora from the grub prompt. I can type out what I tried and the errors I got when trying to boot Fedora manually, but that would take a while to get done so I won't do it unless it's needed.

After looking at this for a while, I decided my main problem was that `update-grub` wouldn't detect Fedora correctly, so I decided to focus on that. Here is my disk outline with the disk unlocked:

(sda2 is Fedora, sda3 is encrypted swap that the Fedora installer set up, sda5 is Xubuntu and I'm pretty sure sda1 is boot. I don't know what sda4 is. **Edit: sda4 is an extended partition containing sda5.**)

```
└──> lsblk
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk  
├─sda4                   8:4    0     1K  0 part  
├─sda2                   8:2    0  70.5G  0 part  
│ └─luks-90a6d2b5-3b2f-45d5-8ddc-624d611822d5
│                      253:0    0  70.5G  0 crypt /media/vatrat/fedora_seabuoy-3
├─sda5                   8:5    0  35.3G  0 part  /
├─sda3                   8:3    0     5G  0 part  
│ └─luks-47f2f83b-4d85-42de-a4b8-f5ad6cd1c119
│                      253:1    0     5G  0 crypt 
└─sda1                   8:1    0     1G  0 part
```

I know that Xubuntu can access sda2 because I copied some files from it.

Comment: I'm adding a similar page, also unanswered: [Update GRUB with encrypted LVM on second volume/drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/550497/update-grub-with-encrypted-lvm-on-second-volume-drive)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.
I used information from https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2, which I had already unsuccessfully tried to use.

I was previously trying to manually boot Fedora with the commands from the section labeled "Encountering the dreaded GRUB 2 boot prompt". However, I was encountering an error at chroot every time. I noticed the section labeled "Additional Scenario" and tried it, and was able to successfully boot into Fedora from the grub prompt.

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod xfs
insmod lvm
set root='hd0,msdos1'
configfile /grub2/grub.cfg
```

hd0,msdos1 is the boot partition. I checked, and there were a bunch of Fedora files in there. In the folder grub2, grub.cfg was the Fedora grub config. I'm not sure where the Xubuntu grub config was stored. Both have different themes. When I booted into Fedora, I ran:

```
$ grub2-install /dev/sda
$ grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

This detected both Fedora and Ubuntu, and when I restarted, the Fedora grub showed up with options for both Fedora and Ubuntu.

I'm not sure why Xubuntu couldn't detect Fedora or how I could prevent this in the future, but I know now how to fix it if it happens again. I'm also not sure what options I would have to use to start Fedora manually, but the grub.cfg file works.